# How to change Odometer value on hover

Tags: jquery

I have implemented Odometer in a site: http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/docs/welcome/

The value of the Odometer needs to have a default value of 100 (which is the sum of six assigned numbers).

I have 6 links. Each link has a data attribute and when you hover over them the Odometer needs to change to show the assigned value. When exiting hover, the odometer needs to return to the default sum.

Really new to jQuery and it's a massive success that I even have Odometer working in the first place, but really struggling with getting much further. Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Current jQuery code to set default value is:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  odometer.innerHTML = 100;
}, 0.100);
```

HTML is:

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div id="odometer" class="odometer count">100</div>
</div>

<div class="sectors"> 
   <ul>
      <li data-value="10" class="n_1"><a href="#" title="">Item 1</a></li>
      <li data-value="25" class="n_2"><a href="#" title="">Item 2</a></li>
      <li data-value="12" class="n_3"><a href="#" title="">Item 3</a></li>
      <li data-value="13" class="n_4"><a href="#" title="">Item 4</a></li>
      <li data-value="22" class="n_5"><a href="#" title="">Item 5</a></li>
      <li data-value="18" class="n_6"><a href="#" title="">Item 6</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to show the links with data-attribute and actual jQuery code. Whatever you have shown is simple vanialla JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from this example:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="odometer" class="odometer">123</div>
<a href="" data-id=134>One</a>    
<a href="" data-id=332>Two</a>    
<a href="" data-id=132>Three</a>    
<a href="" data-id=344>Four</a>    
<a href="" data-id=345>Five</a>
```

**jQuery**:

```
var def = 0;
$(function () {
    $('a').hover(function () {
        def = $(this).attr('data-id');
        odometer.innerHTML = 456;
    }, function () {
        odometer.innerHTML = parseInt(def);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/317/

**About jQuery Hover**: http://api.jquery.com/hover/